# Master page magically changes in ASP.NET MVC Custom View Engine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, master-pages, viewengine

OK I have inherited this code with a custom view engine. All it does is override `FindView` in order to return different views based on the device. Currently, iPad is detected as a mobile device and hence, mobile view is displayed. My task is to change this to desktop view.

There are two master pages `X.master` and `X.Mobile.master`. From the code, you can see that it manually adds `.Mobile` to the master page name for mobile devices. All I have done is setting `isMobile` to `false` for iPad.

The problem is that even though it goes to else statement with `masterName` being `X` (rather than `X.Mobile`), when viewing with an iPad, the view which is returned has `X.Mobile.Master` as its master page. So for iPad, it ends up showing the Desktop View with Mobile Masterpage. Desktop and Mobile versions are all fine. Where (and how) could this possibly happen?

A sample action method:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  return View("Index", "X");
}
```

Here's a simplified version of viewengine:

```
class MobileViewEngine : FixedWebFormViewEngine
{
  public override ViewEngineResult FindView(
    ControllerContext controllerContext,
    string viewName, 
    string masterName, 
    bool useCache
 )
  {
    ViewEngineResult result;
    bool isMobile =
        controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice;

    if (isiPad(controllerContext.HttpContext.Request))
    {
      isMobile = false;
    }

    if (isMobile)
    {
        masterName = masterName + ".Mobile";
        string viewPathAndName = "M/" + viewName;

        //Mobile view retrieved from cache
        result = base.FindView(
            controllerContext,
            viewPathAndName,
            masterName,
            true
        );

            if (result == null || result.View == null)
            {
                //Mobile view retrieved, no cache
                result = base.FindView(
                    controllerContext,
                    viewPathAndName,
                    masterName,
                    false
                );
            }
    }
    else
    {
            //desktop view retrieved
            result = base.FindView(
                controllerContext,
                viewName,
                masterName,
                false
            );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd search your code base for other uses of `IsMobileDevice`.

Comment: That, unfortunately, did not result in anything which could be possibly affecting this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so after looking at ASP.NET MVC (thanks god for open source), I can see that when a request is marked as mobile (`controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice == true`), MVC tries viewname.mobile.cshtml (or .aspx) by default before trying the viewname.cshtml. The same goes for masterpage.

In my case, because there was indeed a masterpage.mobile, it was being rendered. As for the view, because the mobile version was in a separate folder, it was not being picked up and it was falling back to the normal viewname.cshtml.

This whole investigation took me a bit and that has motivated me to share my findings in more details in [my blog](http://www.hossein.com.au).