# MVC4 (FixedRazorViewEngine) not finding my views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to switch views based on a slug I pass in... I can verify the slug and the logic is correct but my views are not found:

Global.asax.cs:

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new DeviceCapableViewEngine());

            DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Insert(0, new DefaultDisplayMode("mobile")
            {
                ContextCondition = Context => Context.Request.Browser["IsMobile"] == "True"
                                                && Context.Request.Browser["IsTablet"] == "False"
            });

            DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Insert(0, new DefaultDisplayMode("")
            {
                ContextCondition = Context => Context.Request.Browser["IsMobile"] == "False"
                                                || Context.Request.Browser["IsTablet"] == "True"
            });
```

DeviceCapableViewEngine:

```
   public class DeviceCapableViewEngine : FixedRazorViewEngine
    {
        public override ViewEngineResult FindView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewName, string masterName, bool useCache)
        {
            ViewEngineResult result = null;
        switch (ThemeContext.GetTheme())
        {
            case "Blue":
                result = base.FindView(controllerContext, string.Format("{0}.{1}", viewName, "blue"), masterName, useCache);
                break;
            case "Red":
                result = base.FindView(controllerContext, string.Format("{0}.{1}", viewName, "red"), masterName, useCache);
                break;
        }

        if (result == null || result.View == null)
            result = base.FindView(controllerContext, viewName, masterName, useCache);

        return result;
    }
```

I have a fairly standard setup and I can confirm that the "blue" or "red" breakpoint are hit. If they are I don't want MVC to inject ".mobile" ... instead I want it to be "viewName.red" ... yet it appears that with my DDR that it will always try to find .mobile with the base call, is this true?

It'll return "viewName.mobile" no matter what. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe unrelated, but: did you check that there are files corresponding to result like "viewName.red.csthml"? Check "SearchedLocations" of result to see if it not looking where you expect...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue ([original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14992495/master-page-magically-changes-in-asp-net-mvc-custom-view-engine/17860014)). When you call base.FindView, you are passing controllerContext as one of the parameters. In there, viewEngine actually looks at the context and if Mobile flag is set to true, it will try finding [viewname].mobile before [viewname].

The solution I came up with (and quite honestly is more elegant IMO) is to put your views in separate folders depending on the device and then in your custom view engine, change the locations in which views should be looked up. This will both provide a logical separation of views depending on the device as well as simplify the view engine.

So your view engine will look something like this:

```
string myViewName = viewName;

switch (ThemeContext.GetTheme())
{
    case "Blue":
        myViewName += ".blue";
        break;
    case "Red":
        myViewName += ".red";                
        break;
}

if (mobileViewShouldNotBeDisplayed)
{

   ViewLocationFormats = new[]
   {
        "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml"
   }; 
}
if (mobileViewShouldBeDisplayed)
{

   ViewLocationFormats = new[]
   {
        "~/Views/{1}/Mobile/{0}.cshtml"
   }; 
}
```

I have written a [blog post](http://hossein.com.au/Post/Extending-ASPNET-MVC-ViewEngine-Render-Device-Specific-Views-Part-Two) which explains this in full details.